# How to use requirements.txt with direct github source in virtual environment

Tags: python, git, pip, python-packaging, pep517

Sometimes I must use python modules from github projects. I can do it in my my_requirements.txt as

```
git+https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools
```

And I use python virtual environment for experiments because I do not want lots of garbage on my machine.

```
pip install -r my_requirements.txt
```

This is approach work all right for good quality github projects with good requirements.txt. Unfortunately there lots of other projects with inconsistent requirements.txt. Those projects requires some modules pre-installation for compilation.

Ok. I wrote in my my_requirements.txt something like

```
numpy
git+https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools
```

and get "module numpy not found" error because PIP do compilation of github project **not in my virtual environment**.

What must I do for github projects compilation **inside** my environment

Here is fulk error message

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Cloning https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools to c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-4kv5zmyx
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-4kv5zmyx'
  Resolved https://github.com/zackhodari/tts_data_tools to commit 3c1aff21ab0fbed1bbfd2ba8a5a16d0eb610ffe1
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (14.9 MB)
Collecting pyreaper
  Using cached pyreaper-0.0.8.tar.gz (124 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_4t7gi1p\pyreaper_27e0fd80dcb141b98b17dd963414e84f\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          import numpy as np
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `pyreaper`: it [imports `numpy`](https://github.com/r9y9/pyreaper/blob/02b1462dd1bb3b3455d1ce910e195179ee79eb63/setup.py#L8) before installing it. So you need to install `numpy` first.

Unfortunately this cannot be done via `my_requirements.txt`. If you add `numpy` in it `pip` downloads and unpacks `numpy` but not fully install it so other packages that require `numpy` cannot import it yet until the entire `my_requirements.txt` is processed. Installation of any package in `my_requirements.txt` that requires any other package that isn't yet installed will fail.

Either you fully install `numpy` before all packages that need it. Or you [report the bug](https://github.com/r9y9/pyreaper/issues), wait until it's fixed and then install any packages without pre-installing `numpy`.

Comment: O! Big thanks. I can install numpy beforehead especially for this case. I am happy with it is specific bug for specific package - not universal law.

Comment: @VadimSmirnov PyPA (Python Packaging Authority) has created [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/r9y9/pyreaper/blob/1d9cd22b324d4e05bde917c86f5e29c5cf6572d5/pyproject.toml) specification to solve the problem — it declares build-time requirements. Unfortunately it seems not to work with [`setup.py`](https://github.com/r9y9/pyreaper/blob/e601fafe6daf7d37f67080dc0ffb79c5e9a67b7b/setup.py). Or there are bugs in this `pyproject.toml`.